# Why/how does Ancestry.com report details of 26 chromosomes?

Tags: autosomal-dna, ancestry.com

The second column of Ancestry's DNA results download is the chromosome number:

```
rsid    chromosome  position    allele1 allele2
rs3131972   1   752721  G   G
```

But it goes from one to 26!  What's up with that?

```
WGroleau@MBP ~ % for PART in head tail; do
for> awk '{print $2}' /Users/WGroleau/DNA/AncestryDNA-WWG.txt  | sort -un | $PART -2
for> done
raw
1
25
26
```

Answer (score 3):

Someone pointed me to https://www.snpedia.com/index.php/Ancestry.com which says:

> - If the Ancestry.com data file says a SNP is from chromosome 23, it's actually from the X chromosome.
> - If it indicates chromosome 24, it's from the portion of the Y chromosome that is not part of the pseudoautosomal region.
> - If it indicates chromosome 25, the designated SNP is from the pseudoautosomal region of the Y chromosome.
> - If it indicates chromosome 26, it's mitochondrial data (which is present in at least some Ancestry data produced since May 2016).